# input type="file" in IE only allows a filepath of 254 characters but windows 7 goes up to 260

Tags: html

I have a simple input tag to upload a file:

```
<input type="file" name="upfile" class="myFile-Input" multiple />
```

This works fine in IE, chrome, FX, but if I exceed 254 IE9 doesn't display the file path and doesnt upload the file. Chrome and Fx handle exceeding 254 just fine. Was wondering if anyone has come across the same problem, if so any good solutions available?

Thanks.

Comment: "It doesn't work at all" means that when you select a file with a path > 254 characters, and upload it, it does not get uploaded? That sounds like a IE9 bug. If it's reproducible, it's reporting-worthy. I don't think there's anything we can do on the front end to fix that (short of using a different upload mechanism altogether)

Comment: I changed the wording of "doesnt work at all". 

Yeah, basically the file path is not displayed and the file doesnt upload.

Comment: can you post some more of your code (you only posted the input html)? how do you upload the file?

Answer (score 0):

i think there is no solution for this problem. Can't we report this bug to Microsoft?